# How to change a particular date column, Date format as DDMMYYYY . in select query

Tags: sql, db2

I have a db2 query wants to change the date format as DDMMYYYY.
The date column is DSAIS.

```
SELECT CODE_CE, MODELE, CHASSIS, DSAIS, DLIVR,TITRE, NOM, PRENOM, CP, VILLE, ADDR_RUE1, 
    ADDR_RUE2, TEL_DOM, TEL_MOBILE, EMAIL 
FROM rk.report 
WHERE DSAIS >= THIS_MONTH(CURRENT DATE - 1 MONTH) 
    AND DSAIS < THIS_MONTH(CURRENT DATE)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use

```
VARCHAR_FORMAT(DSAIS , 'DDMMYYYY')
```

or

```
to_char(DSAIS , 'DDMMYYYY')

SELECT CODE_CE, MODELE, CHASSIS,     VARCHAR_FORMAT(DSAIS , 'DDMMYYYY')
    , VARCHAR_FORMAT(DLIVR, 'DDMMYYYY'),TITRE, NOM, PRENOM, CP, VILLE, ADDR_RUE1, 
    ADDR_RUE2, TEL_DOM, TEL_MOBILE, EMAIL 
FROM rk.report 
WHERE DSAIS >= THIS_MONTH(CURRENT DATE - 1 MONTH) 
    AND DSAIS < THIS_MONTH(CURRENT DATE)
```

Comment: getting the same result as YYYYMMDD not in DDMMYYYY format, when executing the query like   : SELECT CODE_CE, MODELE, CHASSIS, DSAIS, DLIVR,TITRE, NOM, PRENOM, CP, VILLE, ADDR_RUE1, 
 ADDR_RUE2, TEL_DOM, TEL_MOBILE, EMAIL FROM NIG.CARTGAR WHERE DSAIS >= THIS_MONTH(CURRENT DATE - 1 MONTH) 
 AND DSAIS < THIS_MONTH(CURRENT DATE) and to_Char(DSAIS , 'DDMMYYYY')

Comment: There is two column having Date DSAIS and DLIVR. How to apply condition for making format as DDMMYYY for both column?

Comment: not in the odition there you must have dates in the seletc clause